# Is there a reliable way to find which Diving Goggles I've missed?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So I'm working on the [Dive Master achievement](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dive_Master) and my Hero panel lists me at 33/37. I've been [following this guide](http://dulfy.net/2012/11/05/gw2-dive-master-achievement-guide/), and am pretty certain I've completed them all, except for the bugged one in Metrica Province.

How can I find out which Dive points I've missed? Or do I just have to go through them all again? Have any been added in recent updates, such as new ones in Southsun Cove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no current way to see which ones you've completed.

Keep in mind that your dives won't count unless you land in the water after diving, this may explain how you've done them all but didn't get credit for 4 of them.

Your best bet is to run through all of them again, but start with any where you might not have landed in the water.

Comment: Urgh, I was hoping this wasn't the case. Time to redo some of the jumping puzzles also then!

Comment: Similarly, there's also no way to tell which dungeon paths you've completed, and you can only tell if you have 100% of a specific area (for world completion) if you're in that area.

Comment: _Sidetrack_ world completion yes, but the explorer titles are similar to the goggles, in that you've just gotta figure it out yourself. I'm like 2 short on every zone! Even though I'm 100% world complete :)

Comment: In yesterday's update: "Map names on the world map now display completion status."